# Backbone.js Service Call Event Binding

Tags: json, web-services, rest, events, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone, and I am trying to do a get request (getDivisions) and store the response JSON into 'divisions', defined in my defaults. I logged 'divisions' inside the service call, and outside the service call, as seen below.

`define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'service-manager', 'backbone-nested'],
     function(_, Backbone, svgmgr) {
     return Backbone.NestedModel.extend({
        defaults: {
                message: "",
            divisions: []
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this.getDivisions();
        },
        getDivisions: function() { 
                        var that = this;
            svgmgr.Interface.call('getDivisions').done(function(data) { 
                that.set('divisions', data); 
                console.log("Inside the service call: " + that.get('divisions')); 
            }); 
            console.log("Outside service call" + this.get('divisions')); 
        }
    });
});,`

In Dev Tools, the 'Outside the service call' log was called first, returning a blank array (it's default), while the 'Inside the service call' log was called after that, returning the correct response data. This is obviously not what I want.

How do I get this model to run this service call on initialize, so that when I reference 'divisions' I get back the response data?

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need a Model but a Collection, and second Backbone can handle the ajax call for you.

So you have to do like this :

```
var Division = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: /* url to get a single division */,
    defaults: {...}
});

var Divisions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: /* url to get all your divisions */,
    model: Division,
    initialize: function () {
        this.fetch({
            success: function(response) {
                // you get the result here
            }
        });
    }
});
```